# I want to refresh particular view which is display student info without page refreshing in angular js

Tags: angularjs

controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicPopup, $ionicListDelegate, $ionicModal, $window, $timeout, $rootScope) {
   $rootScope.studlist = [];

   $http.get("../services/student_list.php").then(function(response) {
      if (response.data != null) {
         $scope.studlist = response.data;
         console.log($scope.studlist)
      }
   })
});
```

html view

```
<ion-list class="available-scroller" style="margin-top:200px">
   <h2>{{studlist.length}}</h2>
   <ion-item ng-repeat="slist in studlist track by $index" style="margin-top:30px">
      <div class="card padding" style="background-color: rgb(204, 238, 255)" ng-if="studlist.length>0">
         <p>StudentID : {{slist.stud_id}}</p>
         <p>Name : {{slist.firstname+ " "+slist.lastname}}</p>
         <p>Gender : {{slist.gender}}</p>
         <p>MobileNo : {{slist.mobileno}}</p>
         <p>Course : {{slist.course}}</p>
         <p>Semester : {{slist.semester}}</p>
         <p>Username : {{slist.username}}</p>
         <p>
            <button class="button button-assertive button-small icon ion-android-delete" ng-click="delete(slist.stud_id)"></button>
            <button class="button button-assertive button-small icon ion-android-create" ng-click="openModal(slist.stud_id)"></button>
         </p>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: I think your slist in ng-repeat are not update after after list right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

> $timeout

Example

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicPopup, $ionicListDelegate, $ionicModal, $window, $timeout, $rootScope) {
 $rootScope.studlist = [];
 var getStudentsList= function() {
       $http.get("../services/student_list.php").then(function(response) {
          if (response.data != null) {
             $scope.studlist = response.data;
             console.log($scope.studlist)
          }
       })
        $timeout(getStudentsList, 5000);
    }

    });
```